# How can I Copy top half of PDF and insert into new PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

I have an 8.5" x 11" PDF. I'd like to take the top 1/2 of the page, cut it and insert into page 1 of a new PDF. Then, take the bottom 1/2 of the page and insert it into page 2 of the PDF.

I'm essentially trying to split the PDF page in half... All docs I see relate to splitting the individual pages into separate files. I want to essentially copy part of the page and paste it into another doc.

Any help in providing direction using itextsharp? I have used it before and understand the concepts. But, am having a tough time. I'm sure I'll use the rectangle and use the coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are looking to *tile* a PDF. You're not telling us which version of iText you plan on using. Since you seem to be new at this, I'm assuming that you're using iText 7. In that case, please consult [Chapter 6](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-6-reusing-existing-pdf-documents) of the [iText 7 Jump-Start tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/) where we tile a PDF with a single page into a PDF with four pages.

Original PDF:

[image]

Tiled PDF:

[image]

See [TheGoldenGateBridge_Tiles](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples/chapter-6#1783-c06e02_thegoldengatebridge_tiles.java) for the code:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfDocument sourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src));
PdfPage origPage = sourcePdf.getPage(1);
PdfFormXObject pageCopy = origPage.copyAsFormXObject(pdf);
Rectangle orig = origPage.getPageSize();
//Tile size
Rectangle tileSize = PageSize.A4.rotate();
AffineTransform transformationMatrix = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(
    tileSize.getWidth() / orig.getWidth() * 2f,
    tileSize.getHeight() / orig.getHeight() * 2f);
//The first tile
PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage(PageSize.A4.rotate());
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
canvas.concatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, 0, -orig.getHeight() / 2f);
//The second tile
page = pdf.addNewPage(PageSize.A4.rotate());
canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
canvas.concatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, -orig.getWidth() / 2f, -orig.getHeight() / 2f);
//The third tile
page = pdf.addNewPage(PageSize.A4.rotate());
canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
canvas.concatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, 0, 0);
//The fourth tile
page = pdf.addNewPage(PageSize.A4.rotate());
canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
canvas.concatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, -orig.getWidth() / 2f, 0);
// closing the documents
pdf.close();
sourcePdf.close();
```

Changing this example into code that tiles a PDF with 1 page into a PDF with 2 pages, is a matter of using some simple Math.

If you're using iText 5, then the question was already answered many times before. See for instance:

- [Tiling with iText, and adding margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769493)
- [Tile PDF pages vertically with iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586984/tile-pdf-pages-vertically-with-itextsharp)
- [How to tile a pdf to multiple pages with a border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034217/how-to-tile-a-pdf-to-multiple-pages-with-a-border)